# Is Jasper reports suitable for MySQL based reports?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, reporting

I have a situation where I need to generate reports from a Data Mart which is built in MySQl. I have to use open source tools only. Can you please suggest any tools that best fit my requirement? Is Jasper Reports right for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are so many Open source  tool which you can use such as JaspeReport Server and Pentaho.
but I would prefer to use JasperReport server, It has all the capabilities like : -

1. To allow users to make reports and download them as Excel or PDF.
2. Drill downs
   3.Crosstabs
3. Graphical Charts
4. Easy to integrate onto a web app type page full of these reports
5. Easy integration with our databases
6. Easy integration with Java and Eclipse.

You can find more about JasperReport server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jasper-reports/info)

JasperSoft comes default with PostgreSQL database but you can connect through MySQL database.
[Here](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html) you can see comparison of  all other open source reporting based tools.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I will try it. I'm bit confused to see where to start download and Install.http://community.jaspersoft.com/download I have been to this page and got confused which to download. I got MySQl db in windows operating system on which I have to generate reports. Can you suggest some head start on where to start with.

Comment: Download JasperReport Server

Comment: Also download iReports to design your reports.